# Compare the piecewise constant interpolation and piecewise linear interpolation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, numerical-methods

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $\{u_{k}\}$ be a sequence in $X$ with $i\in\mathbb{N}_{0}$. Let $h>0$ be a constant and set $t_k=kh$ and $u(t_k)=u_{k}$ with $k\in\mathbb{N}_0$.
Consider the following two interpolation that is
\begin{align*}
\bar{u}(t)&:=u_{i+1}\mbox{ for }t\in(t_i,t_{i+1}],\\
\hat{u}(t)&:=\frac{t_{i+1}-t}{h}u_{i}+\frac{t-t_{i}}{h}u_{i+1}\mbox{ for }t\in(t_i,t_{i+1}).
\end{align*}
Now let $p\in[1,\infty]$, I would like to compare the $L^p$ norm of these two interpolation with respect to time i.e. whether there exists $C_1>0$ and $C_2>0$ such that
$$C_1\lVert \lVert\hat{u}\rVert_X\rVert_{L^p(0,\infty)}\leq\lVert \lVert \bar{u}\rVert_X\rVert_{L^p(0,\infty)}\leq C_2\lVert \lVert \hat{u}\rVert_X\rVert_{L^p(0,\infty)}.$$
Could this be true?

Comment: Are you looking for the best constants?

Comment: @Kroki, best constants would of course be nice. But I actually only want constants which can make this inequality to be true, not necessarily the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Here the first inequality

  - for $p < \infty$: \begin{align}
    \left\lVert \lVert \hat{u}\rVert_X\right\rVert^p_{L^p(0,\infty)}
    &= h\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \left\|u_i + s \left(u_{i+1}-u_i\right)\right\|^{p} \mathrm d s\\
    &= h\int_{0}^{1} \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\left\|u_i + s \left(u_{i+1}-u_i\right)\right\|^{p}\mathrm d s\\
    &\le h\int_{0}^{1} \left(\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \left\|u_i\right\|^p\right)^{\frac1p} + s \left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \left\|u_{i+1} - u_i\right\|^p\right)^{\frac1p}\right)^{p}\mathrm d s\\
    &\le h \int_{0}^{1} \left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \left\|u_i\right\|^p\right)(1 + 2s)^p\mathrm ds\\
    &= h \left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \left\|u_i\right\|^p\right) \frac{3^{p+1} - 1}{2(p+1)}\\
    &= \frac{3^{p+1} - 1}{2(p+1)}\left\lVert \lVert \bar{u}\rVert_X\right\rVert^p_{L^p(0,\infty)}
    \end{align}
  - for $p = \infty$ \begin{align}
    \left\lVert \lVert \hat{u}\rVert_X\right\rVert_{L^\infty(0,\infty)}
    &= \max_{i\in \mathbb N} \max_{s\in [0,1]}\left\|u_i + s \left(u_{i+1}-u_i\right)\right\|\\
    &\le \max_{i\in \mathbb N} \left\|u_i\right\| + \left\|u_{i+1}\right\| + \left\|u_i\right\|\\
    &\le 3 \left\lVert \lVert \bar{u}\rVert_X\right\rVert_{L^\infty(0,\infty)}
    \end{align}
- The second inequality

  - for $p=\infty$: \begin{align}
    \left\lVert \lVert \hat{u}\rVert_X\right\rVert_{L^\infty(0,\infty)}
    &= \max_{i\in \mathbb N} \max_{s\in [0,1]}\left\|u_i + s \left(u_{i+1}-u_i\right)\right\|\\
    &\ge \max_{i\in \mathbb N} \left\|u_i\right\|\\
    &= \left\lVert \lVert \bar{u}\rVert_X\right\rVert_{L^\infty(0,\infty)}
    \end{align}

Comment: For $p<\infty$, I absolutely agree, but what about $p=\infty$ case. Can we still have something similar?

Comment: I edited my answer to include the case $p = \infty$

Comment: this is really nice, thank you very much. For the rest $p<\infty$ part, I guess we can adopt the answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617536/endpoint-average-inequality-for-a-line-segment-in-a-normed-space ?

Comment: Exactly that the only part left.

Comment: sorry for one more question. In the first $p<\infty$ part, I think the $h$ in front is not needed and why can we interchange the integation and infinite sum?

Comment: It is needed because of the integration. For the interchange every thing is nonnegative you can use Fubini

Comment: @Kroki, can we deduce extraly from this inequality that the strong convergence of the piecewise linear interpolation in $L^p(0,\infty;X)$ for some $p$ is equivalent to the strong convergence of the piecewise constant interpolation in $L^p(0,\infty;X)$?